# array with arabic value not showing and inserting into ini file properly

Tags: php, utf-8, ini

I am implimenting language module using ini file. So i am inserting lable and its value into ini file but the values are inserting like ??? ????? in arabic language.

i have added

```
//in header section 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">     

 //in php section 
   ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');     
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

and also i have add the below line while making string for ini file

```
utf8_encode($elem);
```

I want to add and also update the already added ini values. please tell me how to do everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change db, table,column collation to `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: @Yogesh make it answer.

Comment: but i am not using database. i just add the value in the textbox and while posting if its lable is exist then update or insert the value into the ini file.

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the text, how exactly are you checking it's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Could you provide some code what have you tried?

**t.php**

```
$ file -bi t.php
text/html; charset=us-ascii

<?
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['t'])) {
    $h = fopen('/tmp/h.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($h, $_POST['t']);
    fclose($h);

    readfile('/tmp/h.txt');
    exit;
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">     
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="t">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output after Submit**

[image]

**File after submit**

```
$ file -bi /tmp/h.txt
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**And the web page and submit data**

[image]